# Play a list of youtube videos vb.net Web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Say I have a list of youtube videos

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stYNW4ub5mk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zvjmt4pwtdg
.....
.....

How can I play them one by one and then repeat, eg

```
for j= 1 to 999999999
  for i = 0 to n '(where n is number of videos)
    'play video i
    'how can I tell the ith one ended and to play the next one?
  next i
next j
```

What control, syntax do I use to play the video in my own web page (full size)?

thanks

Comment: Did you do any research yourself already? Whay have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the YouTube player API. (youtube.com/player_api) It handles interactions with embedded YouTube videos.  To detect when a video ends, check for the onPlayerStateChange event. You can add a script section to your html and include this:

*edit*: event.data === 1 is when the player starts, either when it is clicked or if it automatically starts
event.data === 0 is when the video is done.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 1) {            
        #doSomething
    }
    if(event.data === 0)
    {
        #callMethodToIncrementVideo
    }
}
```